# Python で2点間のユークリッドの距離を求めたい

Tags: python

このような感じやりたいのですが上手く行きません。分かる方アドバイスください。

```
p_x = (1, 2, 4)
p_y = (-2, 2, 0)
BEGIN
for i in p_x, p_y:
    i += (p_x - p_y)**2
    distance = i **1/2
    
distance = i

END
print(distance)
```

Comment: どのように「上手く行きません」なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

```py
import math

distance = math.sqrt(sum((x-y)**2 for x, y in zip(p_x, p_y)))
```